# How can I pass an object from a view to a different controller on submit in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, object

First time asking a question on here and fairly new to .NET so apologies in advance! (Any help greatly appreciated!)

I've got a controller and a create view for a 'Builder' class which stores user inputted values. On submit, I want to be able to pass the instance of builder class to a new controller called 'SignLine' so I can use the value from the builder object in my SignLine object.

**Builder Controller**

(I have the redirect to action, how can I pass the builder class instance (called 'customSign') into the create method of the SignLine controller?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,OrderNo,ItemNo,BackgroundColour,DigitColour,DigitSize,TextLine1,TextLine2,HoleOption")] CustomSign customSign)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      return RedirectToAction("Create", "SignLineController" /*Pass created intance here*/);
  }
}
```

**SignLine Controller**

I've changed the SignLine create a method to take in a builder class instance as a parameter.

```
// GET: SignLine/Create
public ActionResult Create(Builder customSign)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: you just need to set `action='/SignLine/Create` in your `form`.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` has an overload that takes a third argument of type `object`, which essentially appends a query string to the 302 response Location header generated by the method, by using the property names of the `object`.

If `CustomSign` and builder share the same property names, you can simply do the following:

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "SignLineController", customSign);
```

Otherwise you will need to create either an anonymous object or `Builder` instance e.g.

```
var builder = new Builder
{
    Prop1 = customSign.PropA,
    Prop2 = customSign.PropB
};
return RedirectToAction("Create", "SignLineController", builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view has @model attribute set on its top like this

```
@model Project_Name.ViewModels.Builder;
```

then all you have to do is create an action link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Create", "SignLine", new { customSign = Model }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

When you click on this submit button your model will be passed on to the controller.